# Table named 'like' in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I didn't realize 'like' was a keyword in SQL when I built my table. Now I get an error when I try insert into the row because 'like' is a SQL keyword.

*error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW(), 'kirkins@gmail.com', '12345678')' at line 1*

Can I modify my insert to specify that I mean the table named like and not the like keyword?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO like VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW(), '$email', '$post_id')";
```

Comment: Try escaping the table name: `like`

Comment: `\`like\``, even. (Stack Overflow uses backticks for markup.)

Comment: Even better: rename your table so it does not used a reserve word.  It will make your coding much easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: Yeah I appreciate knowing how to do it, but I think I'll rename the table.

Comment: `\`like\`` escape it this way! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `like` VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW(), '$email', '$post_id')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape the table name with ticks:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `like` VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW(), '$email', '$post_id')";
```