# PHP/MySQL table named "int"

Tags: php, sql

Is there any reason why 'int' would be an illegal table name to use with a SQL query in PHP?

I kept getting an error with that table name in my query.  Only when I renamed the table was I able to get my query to work.

Comment: Using reserved words are always going to be problematic. But might work as long as all queries correctly quote identifiers.

Comment: It's not illegal. CREATE TABLE `int`(`column` int(11)) works fine.

Comment: php would think that the `int` you refered was a `declaration` not a `table name`

Comment: In any case, it's a bad idea to use reserved keywords as your own column or table name. It's possible to do it, but if you can stay away from it, please do so.

Comment: because that is a reserved keyword! ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134706/table-named-like-in-mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query should use backticks to enclose the table name if it contains [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM `int` WHERE ... etc.
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought maybe it was a reserved word, but couldn't find out for sure - or how to solve the problem.  Your answer did both.